# how do i use an id as a variable using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, variables

I'm not sure if I'll describe this very well... but:

I have a div, and I'd like to use the id of the div as a variable in my jQuery function.

There's a variable with the same name as the ID value, and it has already been declared as a number .. at the moment I get NaN.

I just need the variable whatIsIt to land in the function as aqstn - the jsfiddle has an alert with the id.. but it doesn't translate into the number of what it is in the code.. if you know what I mean.!?

To better explain, here's a js fiddle of the problem!
http://jsfiddle.net/CpFqk/

jQuery:

```
$('.add').click(function() {

    whatIsIt = $(this).attr('id');
    alert (whatIsIt);
    base = (base+whatIsIt);
    // base = (base+aqstn); --> This works OK
    // Some maths to get +- 15%
    fifteen = (base*.15)
    price1 = (base+fifteen)
    price2 = (base-fifteen)

    $(".price span.more").html(price1);
    $(".price span.less").html(price2);
});
```

Comment: Why do you need the ID as a variable?

Comment: Use 'parseInt' on the id value to get the number from ots String representation.

Comment: @BotskoNet i wanted to use the id so that i could have a nice tidy jQUery file and use $(this) instead of writing a function for each thing the user could click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an object instead if you want to use the id as the variable

```
var data = {aqstn : 236};
```

Then to get the value out of the data object

```
whatIsIt = data[$(this).attr('id')]; // or data[this.id]
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/rgx9f/)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, perfect! - and all the other replies. so much knowledge! I need to go and lean about data objects ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share variable between HTML and Javascript in such manner. Instead, you will need to use a `rel` attribute to save & specify the integer value as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/qwFCk/1/

Comment: `rel` is not a valid attribute for a div (at least not in the HTML5 spec). Using a valid custom attribute like `data-val` would be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `var` from before `aqstn` it will be available as a property of `window` and you can access it via a named parameter. `window[whatIsIt]`

I don't recommend you do this at all, though; I'm just providing it as a last resort.  wirey's answer is the more correct one.

http://jsfiddle.net/CpFqk/1/

Answer (score 0):

You must put your variable "aqstn" into an object such as window (or any):

```
window["aqstn"] = 236;
```

Then use the id as a key for this object

```
whatIsIt = $(this).attr('id');
alert( window[whatIsIt] );
```

I don't know what is you purpose but there is probably a smarter way to do that :) Did you have a look on the [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method ?

Answer (score 0):

because converting this id string into a variable doesn't seem like it'll be very tidy once i add all the prices, here's another approach. it keeps the prices out of the html.

check if the id == the variable name (string) - if it does define a new variable that's used in the calculation. it means defining one for each of the prices but.. :/

```
if(whatIsIt=='ovrhead'){ var jammin = ovrhead };
if(whatIsIt=='aqstn'){ var jammin = aqstn };

base = (base+(jammin));
```

Comment: genius work around. lol